# WaitForSeconds Not Delaying Audio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to code my script plays audio then use WaitForSeconds to wait 31 seconds then play another audio clip this is so it waits 2 seconds longer then the previous audio. But it doesn't wait to play that second audio clip. So they play at the same time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ButtonActionHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource source;
    public AudioClip drnefariotalk1;
    public AudioClip childtalk;
    public AudioSource AudioSource;
    public AudioClip drnefariotalk2;

    IEnumerator Timer()
            {
                source.PlayOneShot(drnefariotalk1);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(31f);
                source.PlayOneShot(childtalk);
            }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your audio source is set to `PlayOnAwake`, which is causing confusion.  Code looks fine.

Comment: To add to what @hijinxbassist wrote, you seem to have two AudioSource references, so it's possible you have two objects with the AudioSource component, one of which has PlayOnAwake

Comment: I already fixed the problem